# Databricks: where are all the notebook files and folders using %sh?

Tags: databricks

I am trying to locate the workspace files from a notebook magic command in terminal mode %sh.

We use an onprem bibucket which isn't supported by databricks. I want to run git commands "manually" in scripts. To git init or do anything I need to know the address of the folder in terminal mode (%sh).

If I run the below command, it seems to run indefinitely:

```
%sh find / -name FOLDERNAME -type d
```

If I run this, it gives me the address relative to the workspace folder but there is no workspace folder in the terminal.

```
%scala
dbutils.widgets.text("notebook", dbutils.notebook.getContext().notebookPath.get)
```

I know databricks-cli is an option but that is too manual and prone to issues since it involves downloading the files to a local computer before the commit and vice versa.

Comment: Are you asking where DB notebooks and libs are stored? and a way to retrieve them through `%sh`?

Comment: yes, I want to know where the files are, not using the workspace-cli.

Comment: They are stored in the cloud. You will not be able to find them using `%sh`